# Different marker when a comment was great-comment-voted by the OP

Tags: feature-request, comments, accepted-answer

Some comments are helpful in supplementing to questions/answers, but a usual reply would be a "thanks, edited that in". Instead, the OP should be able to mark that comment in a special way (say, "comment accepted" by turning the number green) to acknowledge the help without producing a noise comment.

[image: "accept comment"]

Comment: Interesting idea (although I don't think the check mark is the right symbol here), but bad screenshot

Comment: @Pekka: I'm afraid the auto-upload makes a jpg of my png :( However, I also made mistake I fixed now... Also, you're right about the checkmark. I'll think of something else

Answer (score 1):

I (sort of) like the basic idea here.  Often, I've wanted to acknowledge a comment without leaving a reply - indicating to the comment author that I appreciate/found their comment useful.  It certainly would cut down on a lot of comments that go like:

> @user: thanks.

However, there's the obvious problem of interference with "hotness" applied to comment scores.  When a score reaches a certain threshold it changes colour, ranging from cold to supernova.  Also, if you change the colour range to greens for every vote on a comment for the post author it signifies importance of his vote above other all other votes which isn't always the case.

Most certainly, I wouldn't like to acknowledge *all* comments I vote for in this manner.  I might just find a comment funny rather than particularly useful and I don't think casting my vote on that comment should change the way it looks to other users.

It's a nice-ish idea if it could be implemented in a better way without adding any bloat to the system.

Comment: I didn't notice the already existing colouration, and your "I might just find a comment funny" point is a good point that this should be handled separately. But, as devinb [states](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63069/different-marker-when-a-comment-was-great-comment-voted-by-the-op/63072#63072), using an "accepted comment check" also wouldn't be exactly right. Back to the drawing board...

Answer (score 0):

Comments are supposed to be lightweight throwaways. They are simply added on bits of commentary.

It is meaningful to have a checkmark on the answer that only the OP gives out. The OP is saying "this is the correct answer to my question."

Is that meaningful when applied to a comment? "This comment is the most correct comment." Even "this is the best" comment isn't really meaningful because comments don't have a succinct purpose. They are used for chatter, clarification, denigration, cooperation, capitulation and sometimes gibberish. Each of those is a *valid* use of a comment. So what criteria are the checkmarks to be distributed based on.

Comment: I agree with you and Pekka that the checkmark is not the correct idea. I just thought, somehow it would be nice to indicate that the comment did not just help others but also the OP in improving the answer/question. Maybe a green number instead? I didn't mean to say "best comment", only "comment that helped answer's author / OP"

Comment: @Tobias The trouble is that commenting is not *directed* at the OP. Answers are directed at the OP, that is the point of them. but comments can be directed any which-way. If your comment is meant to be particularly helpful, it should be an answer.

Comment: maybe I mixed up OP and "author of the post the is commented on" a bit, sorry for that. I meant e.g. if I post an answer, find a comment (incidentally, yours in this case) an addition my answer should have, I'd like to mark that instead of posting noise à la "thanks, that's right". The feature should of course not be abused to promote comments that were not really improving the answer's (or question's, if that is commented on) quality.

Comment: @Tobias, however a problem still exists in a few lights. A) can it be given more than once? B) Sycophantism, wouldn't it just be given out to people who write things that the OP *already agrees with*. This problem exists with the answer checkmark, but with the comment checkmark it would be even more prevalent, because there is no way to *downvote* comments, so there's no downside to leaving such a comment.

Comment: @Tobias, You, being open-minded, are able to have a discussion with someone who disagrees with you. Most people are not so generous. They don't like it when their ideas are questioned.